# List of links that navigate to same component which renders the link specific content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am new to React and I'm currently working on a personal project aiming to better learn React. I have a problem statement to solve and I need ideas to go forward. The problem is as follows.

I have a list of links on my component. When I click on a link, it should route to a component which displays content(say....a text) based on what I clicked from the list of links previously. There should only be a single component which displays content based on which link was clicked from the list of links.

In order to solve the above problem statement(Sorry for digressing, but this will really help me solve the above), I thought of rendering based on user input first. I wanted to load and display a PDF whose URL is provided as user input. PDF is located in the device directory (D: drive). I have tried it out as follows:

App.js

```
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var InputComp = require('./inputComp');

var App = createReactClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return { value: '' };
},

handleChange: function (valueFromChild) {
    this.setState({ value: valueFromChild });
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="container">
          <InputComp newVal={this.handleChange} />            
          <object width="800" height="470" data={this.state.value}></object>
          </div>               
          </div>
    );
}
});

module.exports = App;
```

InputComp.js

```
"use strict";

 var React = require('react');
 var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

 var InputComp = createReactClass({  
getInitialState: function () {
    return { userInput: '' };
},

onChange: function (event) {
    this.setState({
        userInput: event.target.value
    });
    this.props.newVal(event.target.value);
},

render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="container form1">
            <input type="text" style={{ width: '800px' }} placeholder="Enter URL" value={this.state.userInput} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = InputComp;
```

This is done to dynamically load the PDF if it resides at the directory URL provided by the user. When I inspect in Chrome, the value of the data attribute in the object tag changes but the PDF is not loading on the page.

Please do suggest how to solve this. Example codes are most welcome!
Please do comment if clarity is needed.

Thanks

Comment: "Example codes are most welcome!". Questions with code showing what you already tried are most welcome.

Comment: You should take a look at [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment trixn, I shall update the question by adding what I tried out............

Comment: Hi Titus, I have tried using react-router. I will update the question with what I tried.

Comment: H, I have updated my question. Please do comment and suggest.